# Get data from a chain of lists

Tags: javascript

I have 3 different lists which I get in 3 separate API calls.

1. `persons` 2. `cars` 3. `categories`

What I need to do is:

1. Get `persons` -> then pull cars ids from the `persons` list
2. Gel `cars` based on the cares ids I got on #1 -> then pull categories ids from the `cars` list
3. Get `categories` based on categories ids I got on #2 -> then get all `categories` names and `cars` names.

Desired output:

```
tags=[{"categoryName":"", "carName":""},{"categoryName":"", "carName":""}...]
```

This is what I did, I don't find it much readable, would appreciate any refactor/alternative

```
let persons= [
      {carId: '020e49c9-3c31-4abf-b83c-d2ebdc026300'},
      {carId: '0fb208e4-dec7-44d1-aea4-e15712455146'},
      {carId: '00a10008-09c3-4bab-81de-34c1eae3e0ca'},
      {carId: '00a10008-09c3-4bab-81de-34c1eae3e0ca'},
      {carId: '14d7456c-6a94-467f-a1a0-bcb15c9120ef'}
    ]

    persons= new Map(
      persons.map(p => [p.carId, p])
    )
    
     categories= new Map(
      categories.data.map(c => [c.id, c.name])
    )

    const carsPerCategory = cars.data
      .filter(({id}) => persons.get(id))
      .map(({name, categoryId}) => ({
        description: name,
        category: categories.get(categoryId)
      }))
```

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @pacmaninbw Ok, will know for next tine, thanks for your comment

Comment: In this case I left the edit because the person that answered should have just commented and let you improve the post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Inconsistent Requirements

You state the following

> What I need to do is:
> Get persons -> then pull cars ids from the persons list
> Gel cars based on the cares ids I got on #1 -> then pull categories ids from the cars list
> Get categories based on categories ids I got on #2 -> then get all categories names.

And then show some example output (which looks like it's malformed)

> tags=[
> {
> "categoriesName":"",
> "carsName":""
> }

Which seems to have a different form than the final step in the "What I need to do is" description.

This inconsistency and malformed example output makes it slightly hard to review - but if we assume that the example output is what is desired, the following implementation may be useful

### Possible Implementation

```javascript
const carIds = new Set([Object.entries(persons).map(([key, value]) => value)]);

categoryNamesByCategoryId = new Map(categories.data.map(c => [c.id, c.name]));

const carsPerCategory = cars.data
  .filter(({ id }) => carIds.has(id))
  .map(({ name, categoryId }) => ({
      carName: name,
      categoryName: categoryNamesByCategoryId.get(categoryId)
    })
  );
```

### Naming

I like to name my mappings something like `{values}By{key}`. So in this case, the `categories` `Map` would be `categoryNamesByCategoryId`. I think this is expresses the nature of the data structure more-so than the name `categories` would imply a list / array / set of categories (to me, at the very least).

`carsPerCategory` also seems misnamed - it looks like an array of objects which have two properties - a `description` property and a `category` property. Something like `carNameAndCategory` or `cars` might be better, but honestly, I think a `Map` data structure might be more natural here where you have the car name as the key and the category as the value.

Also note that the `description` property seems improperly named as it's really the car *name*, at least based on what I can infer from the property destructuring, and that the `category` property doesn't refer to a `Category` object or multiple `Category` properties but the category name. I think for readers, it would be clearer if `category` was renamed to `categoryName`.

### Data Structures

I don't think you need a `persons` `Map` - you're only using the `persons` `Map` to filter data, so basically using the `carId` keys as a `Set` to filter against. I think it's more natural to simply produce that `Set` vs. allocating a `Map` where the `value` is not necessary.

One additional thing - it was never clear if an additional filter was needed for categories, to guarantee that every car had a non-`undefined` `categoryName` associated with it.

### Variable Reassignment

I think the `let persons` variable declaration to then re-assign `persons` shortly after is not desirable.

First of all, `persons` was initially an array of objects, then was assigned to a `Map`. These are pretty different data structures and would seem odd that the same variable could represent both data structures on a philosophical level.

Secondly, I believe you could generate the `Map` in a single statement like

```javascript
const personsById = new Map(
   ...[
    //data
   ].map(person => [person.carId, person])
)
```

The upside is that you can declare `personsById` as a `const` and avoid using a `let`.

Comment: If the question is unclear, please leave a comment instead of an answer. If you answer and the question is improved, there will be answer invalidation while the answer was premature.